# How can I create Subcollection in document?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create under every Restaurant document empty Subcollection where I will be adding new reservations. All Restaurant documents are in Restaurants collection.

```
let \_ = Firestore.firestore().collection("Restaurants").document(userUID).setData(\[
"userName": userName,
"userEmail": email,
"maxSittingPlaces": sittingplaces,
"description": description,
"openingHours": openingHours,
"adress": adress,
"phoneNumber": phone,
"actualSittingPlaces": sittingplaces,
"imageURL:,": imgURL.self\])

                    let _ = 

-->  Firestore.firestore().collection("Restaurants").document(userUID).collection("Reservations")
```

I don' know how to write command to create Subcollection Reservations in every document Reservation.

[image]

Comment: Did you read the documentation for this? What have you tried? Where do you struggle?

Answer (score 0):

In firebase, The collection wont be created unless you write something to it. So remember to write something in the collection you just created.Here's the code for it.

```
let reservationRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("Restaurants").document(userUID).collection("Reservations")

let reservationData = [  "userName": userName,  "userEmail": email]

reservationRef.addDocument(data: reservationData)
```

Happy Coding :)